# MutationObserver for only the last mutation

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I'm using the `MutationObserver` to save position changes in a draggable object.

It looks like this:

```
 let observer = new MutationObserver( (mutations) => {
        mutations.forEach( (mutation) => {
            this.builderData[element.id].$position.left = element.style.left;
            this.builderData[element.id].$position.top = element.style.top;
            this.saveBuilderData();
        });
    });
    observer.observe(element, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });
```

However, this run for every pixel changed, so it is a lot saving operations being ran. I would like to only save after it has stop mutating for about 1 second, or that each callback excludes the previous one. I already did something like this with **RxJava**, but did not worked with `MutationObserver`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use [debounce](https://github.com/component/debounce) to reduce amount of stored information

Comment: I wish to see a better answer here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add a simple 1 second delay via setTimeout.

This way previous callbacks are discarded and the style is only changed after 1 second of inactivity:

```
let timer;
let observer = new MutationObserver( (mutations) => {
  if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    mutations.forEach( (mutation) => {
        this.builderData[element.id].$position.left = element.style.left;
        this.builderData[element.id].$position.top = element.style.top;
        this.saveBuilderData();
    });
  }, 1000);
});
observer.observe(element, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });
```

Comment: It worked great, dude!
I tried using timeout, but I didn't knew about this clearTimeout method =(.
Cheers man!